# cURL function not working

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to send bulk text messages from a website.. so im using an api.. i have created the `$sendString` variable to the exact url to use the api.. but for some reason the cURL function is not working for this particular URL...

I tried using another function with this api to check my credit balance and it works... i even tried pasting the `$sendString` variable manually into the link box and it worked! So I know that cURL and the api are both working, but just not for sending out my texts from the website... any ideas?

```
//Create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

//Set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$sendString");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//Grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

//Close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What is `$sendString` for this request?  Set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true and then do `$data = curl_exec($ch); var_dump($data);` What do you see?  If it returns false, check the value of `curl_error($ch);`

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "{$sendString}");

add curly bracket for the sendString variable

Comment: it says false.. and the error is:
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Answer (score 1):

Use [curl_setopt_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php) for parse all string of url
Like this:

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
$options = array
(
    CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER=>true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>$browser_id
);
curl_setopt_array($curl_handle,$options);
$server_output = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

var_dump($server_output)
```